# Inserting UTF8 data into image field in sql server 2005 from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, utf-8

I have a string made of of xml markup which i encoded using UTF8. When i insert it into sql server image filed it only inserts the first 28 bytes or characters.

Here is my code:

```
  UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
  byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(file.Value);
  string update = String.Format("Update xdpath set content = '{0}' where dpath = '{1}';", encodedBytes, file.Key);
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(update, conn);
  com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Result in content field of type image : 0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D.

There is content in the file which is very verbose. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql parameters

```
SqlCommand ImageCommand = new SqlCommand("", (SqlConnection)connection, (SqlTransaction)Transaction);

ImageCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@"Update xdpath set content = @ByteArray where dpath = '{0}'",file.Key);

ImageCommand.Parameters.Add("@ByteArray", SqlDbType.Image).Value = (object)encodedBytes ?? DBNull.Value;
```